# Searching multiple tables using a keyword in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword

```
SELECT * from vehicle_adv_details
        LEFT JOIN vehicle_description on vehicle_adv_details.id=vehicle_description.vehicleid
        LEFT JOIN vehicle_extras on vehicle_adv_details.id=vehicle_extras.vehicleid
        LEFT JOIN vehicle_technical_features on vehicle_adv_details.id=vehicle_technical_features.vehicleid
        LEFT JOIN vehicle_photo on vehicle_adv_details.id=vehicle_photo.vehicleid

                            ) UNIONALL

    (SELECT * FROM propertysale_adv_details
        LEFT JOIN propertysale_adv_description ON propertysale_adv_details.id = propertysale_adv_description.propertysalesid
        LEFT JOIN propertysale_adv_listeragent ON propertysale_adv_details.id = propertysale_adv_listeragent.propertysalesid
        LEFT JOIN propertysale_adv_listerowner ON propertysale_adv_details.id = propertysale_adv_listerowner.propertysalesid
        LEFT JOIN propertysale_adv_photos ON propertysale_adv_details.id = propertysale_adv_photos.propertysalesid

                            ) UNIONALL

    (SELECT * from propertyrent_adv_details 
        LEFT JOIN propertyrent_description on propertyrent_adv_details.id=propertyrent_description.propertyrentid
        LEFT JOIN propertyrent_landlord_details on propertyrent_adv_details.id=propertyrent_landlord_details.propertyrentid
        LEFT JOIN propertyrent_photo on propertyrent_adv_details.id=propertyrent_photo.propertyrentid
        WHERE advtitle LIKE '%villa%'
                            )                                                       

        WHERE advtitle LIKE '%villa%' OR kilometer LIKE '%villa%'
        OR price LIKE '%villa%' OR description LIKE '%villa%'
```

Comment: This is my query... I dint get any results.

Comment: Please help me to get result

Comment: all these `ropertysaleropertysaleropertysaleropertysaleropertysale` makes me dazzled. Are you positively sure you can't use a single table instead of all these numerous field-like tables?

Comment: column count matches on each select? otherwise union wont work

Comment: * for Select is no good idea with union, because you can't be sure if the table-columns match (see @waygood)

Answer (score 0):

How `advtitle` `kilometer` `price` and `description` columns which are defenitely have different types and contents are just `LIKE` a constant string `villa`!

is the `villa` a magic word for your where condition?